# problem with \cite{} in multipart article with separate bibliographies for each \include{} file

Tags: citing, include

I've got a little problem with the consistency of \cite{} across multiple \include{} files, where each such file gets its own bibliography. Just to be clear: I'm not using natbib.

Each \include{} file gets its own ".aux" file, so it's easy to just run bibtex on each and get separate ".bbl" files, which I can \input where desired in each \include{} file (after commenting out the \bibliographystyle{} and \bibliography{} lines, since I don't need them anymore after I've got the ".bbl" files). And all that is working as I want.

The problem is that when the same reference occurs in two or more of the \include{} files, the \cite{} command always inserts the reference number from the ".bbl" file of the last file, even when the \cite{} is in one of the earlier files. Since each ".bbl" file numbers the references differently (because they're not generally the same references), that's inconsistent with the reference numbers in the earlier ".bbl" files.

Hopefully there's some easy way to fix this little problem!

Comment: try the chapterbib package. It handles this. biblatex handles it naturally too.

Comment: That did it (with the sectionbib option); thank you!